# Backbone sent userinfo after login

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm making some kind of pinterest backbone application. (post pics/vids/text etc to remember later) It is the first time I try to make a register/login in backbone.

I have a homeView and an OverviewView at the moment.
If a user registers now I use this function:

```
this.usersCollection.create({

    firstName: this.$el.find('.registerFirstName').val(),
    lastName: this.$el.find('.registerLastName').val(),
    email: this.$el.find('.registerEmail').val(),
    password: this.$el.find('.registerPassword').val()

}, {
success: function(response){
    Backbone.history.navigate("#overview", true);

}
```

});

this is working, it creates the user in my database and redirects to overview. But now on overview I have to know which id this user has (same if login instead of register). What is the best way to either send the model that was created or its id to the overviewView so it can get items from the database that correspond to that user?

Thanks in advance,
Pieter-Jan

Comment: Why don't you create an access token and store user details in a cookie and then access the user details via the token.

Answer (score 0):

I think storing the user model in the browser `localStorage` would be the best option, and it's [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) in everything but Opera Mini these days

```
this.usersCollection.create({
    firstName: this.$el.find('.registerFirstName').val(),
    lastName: this.$el.find('.registerLastName').val(),
    email: this.$el.find('.registerEmail').val(),
    password: this.$el.find('.registerPassword').val()
}, {
    success: function(model){
        window.localStorage.set('user', model);
        Backbone.history.navigate("#overview", true);
    }
});
```

You can retrieve it later with

```
var user = window.localStorage.get('user');
```

Comment: I think it would be pretty easy for people to change data in local storage or cookies to access pages they shouldn't

Comment: Ahh, so maybe you need to override the navigate method as suggested in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430086/backbone-passing-a-model-to-router